# "The name "X" does not exist in the current context" ASP.NET Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. I created a classic ASP.NET website.
2. I added Default.aspx and added Abc class to App_Code folder.
3. I have WriteSample() static method in ABC class.
4. I'm running the project no problem.
5. I get an error when I try to compile and publish.

**The codes are as follows;**

Abc Class

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
        
        public class Abc
        {
        public Abc()
        {
          
        }
    
        public static void WriteSample()
        {
    
        }
    }
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Abc.WriteSample();
    }
}
```

**the error message is as follows**

"The name "Abc" does not exist in the current context"

Why? Please help me.

**EDIT:**

I tried it on another computer, no problem. I can publish.

!Try the code yourself before commenting. very important forum rule!

**Now,**

I reinstalled visual studio, repaired it, tried different versions. i am having the same problem again. Why?

Comment: Seems like you need to learn more about classes and objects. For a start you haven't put your Abc class in a namespace and included that namespace in your aspx.cs file, so that file probably knows nothing about it. And secondly, in order to run the WriteSample() method you'll need to instantiate the class (unless you change the method to be static). You're missing some core concepts here, I suggest going and following some relevant tutorials or getting a book on C#.

Comment: P.S. If you're just starting to learn, don't bother learning the old, obsolete ASP.NET Webforms. No-one is making new stuff with that anymore. Razor Pages, Blazor and MVC are the modern flavours of ASP.NET's UI frameworks, and will (unlike webforms) run on the latest .NET 6 platform.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I stopped working professionally a long time ago.
I'm trying a project. I don't think I need to add namespace.
there is another problem. I can't look at the book I wrote myself because it's too old. I am old now (;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

1. Right click on your Abc-classfile and select "Properties". Then choose Build Action → Compile
2. Now you should be able to include the namespace in the ASPX-codebehind-file. For instance right click on the error and choose Quick-actions → Include the using-statement.

Comment: Tnx u. but this time I am getting this error.
The type or namespace name 'myNamespace' was not found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: I don't think it's a syntax error. there is something else

Comment: Are you really sure everything is OK with your namespaces?
can't you try to add a namespace to your Abc file as well as the Page-file
namespace myNamespace { ... }

Comment: I tried here removing the namespace and it did break. I'm not sure what version of .net you using, the later ones allow you to use file scoped namespaces without {}

Comment: if you have a look at this example, where I actually have the same namespace for both files, then no using is needed (but ugly...) https://i.imgur.com/OypizZb.png

Comment: thank you for your effort. but when i add namespace i get same error. And it works when I try it on another computer. with my computer / system / etc. a problem but I couldn't solve it. :(

Comment: if you right click your project → properties, what is your target framework?

Comment: 4.7.2 Framework version